# Snowflake Ingest Pipeline - Automatically Remove Ingest Files From Source?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are wanting to ingest events into snowflake from S3 bucket. I know this is possible from this documentation: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-s3.html

But after the files have been ingested we'd like to either delete the files that have been ingested or remove it form the ingest bucket.

[image]

1: Events loaded into ingest bucket via Firehose (or direct)
2: Snowflake automatically ingests events from this bucket
3: Snowflake either A) moves the files to a new bucket or B) sends a message (SNS?) to a process (lambda) to move the processed file out of the ingest bucket.

Is this possible with Snowflake? I'd like to use the automatic pipeline feature but it looks like the only way I can get this behavior would be to write the pipeline ourselves.

Comment: Are you leveraging streams/tasks inside Snowflake as part of the pipeline post-Snowpipe?  This isn't quite what you want, but you could leverage tasks and streams to execute `REMOVE` commands against your S3 bucket based on new data being loaded by the PIPE.

Comment: I looked into streams but found they didn't work the way I was hoping. In addition to even data we stream in a lot of user profile data that updates already existing rows. The stream feature was geared towards streaming data that doesn't change.

I probably will be using tasks. I need to look into them but is it possible to have a task kick off after a pipe finishes or is it always a routine?

Comment: That's not actually how streams work.  Streams actually give you the changes to a table whether they were inserts, updates, or deletes.  The point of the stream in this case is you can run a task every minute, but only if the stream contains new data which would indicate that a pipe has completed.  When there isn't anything in the stream, nothing would run.  So, this gives you an alternative to what you are looking for despite having some latency.  You are not currently able to execute a task based on the status of a pipe....yet.